# Morris chart won't accept my json data but accepts hardcoded example data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, morris.js

`dashboard_test.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <%= content_tag(:div, "", id: "shoppers_chart", data: {shoppers_data: @test}) %>
</div>
```

`brands_controller.rb` file:

```
def dashboard_test

    @test = [
        {period: '2010 Q1',
        iphone: 2666,
        ipad: 542,
        itouch: 2647},
        {period: '2010 Q2',
        iphone: 2778,
        ipad: 2294,
        itouch: 2441} ]
end
```

`shoppers.js` file with hardcoded data:

```
$(function() {

    Morris.Area({
        element: 'shoppers_chart',
        data: [
             {period: '2010 Q1',
             iphone: 2666,
             ipad: null,
             itouch: 2647},
             {period: '2010 Q2',
             iphone: 2778,
             ipad: 2294,
             itouch: 2441} ],
        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['ipad', 'iphone', 'itouch'],
        labels: ['ipad', 'iphone', 'itouch'],

        pointSize: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true

    });

});
```

This code ^^ works fine. the chart is displayed.

`shopper.js` with data being pulled from the `dashboard_test.html.erb` file:

```
$(function() {

    Morris.Area({
        element: 'shoppers_chart',
        data: $('#shoppers_chart').data('shoppers_data'),

        xkey: 'period',
        ykeys: ['ipad', 'iphone', 'itouch'],
        labels: ['ipad', 'iphone', 'itouch'],

        pointSize: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true

    });

});
```

This code ^^ does not work. The chart is completely blank - no x or y axis markers or anything at all.

in my chrome dev tool, both times, this is the output for the correlated div:

```
<div id="shoppers_chart" 
     data-shoppers-data="[
       {"period":"2010 Q1","iphone":2666,"ipad":542,"itouch":2647},
       {"period":"2010 Q2","iphone":2778,"ipad":2294,"itouch":2441}]"   
     style="position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
```

I've tried adding `html_safe` to my `content_tag`, I've tried switching it over to coffeescript.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: From chrome dev tools what is the output of $('#shoppers_chart').data('shoppers_data')[0]

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)` is the error when I put it in my chrome dev tools console

Answer (score 2):

The content of data is a string:

```
//                         ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ STRING
data: $('#shoppers_chart').data('shoppers_data')
```

while your charts expect an object:

```
data: JSON.parse($('#shoppers_chart').data('shoppers_data'))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That gives me an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`. The output for the correlated div is the same as it's been